# associate number in number field with the number of newly created js div's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of number input fields, labeled small & medium.., and a set of div's with the label small and medium. When you add a number to the small number input field a text input insertsAfter the div labeled small. When you subtract a number from the small number input field, the text input field that was recently added is removed. the adding and removing of the text input is be the last one in the list. This same thing goes for the medium number field and medium label/textfield

please see JSFiddle for reference
http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/53/

Right now my script is working correctly when I click the up or down buttons on the number field. But When I type in, for instance 5 in the small number field, only one new div/name input fields appears under the label small. I need the adding and subtracting of these input fields to be generated when I use the arrows and when I type in a number. So when I type in "5" 5 name/text input fields should appear under the associated label.

html :

```
<div id="product-1">
<div class="size-field">
    <div id="size-label">s</div>
    <div class="number-input">
        <input id="Small" class="product-quantity" type="number" name="Small" 
min="0" max="9999" data-product-id="1"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="size-label">m</div>
<div class="number-input">
    <input id="Medium" class="product-quantity" type="number" 
name="Medium" min="0" max="9999" data-product-id="1"></input>
</div>
<div class="name-number-header">
    <h5>HEADER<h5></div>
<div class="name-number-field-container" data-size="Small">small:
</div>
    <div class="name-number-field-container" data-size="Medium">medium:
</div>
    </div>

<br clear="all">

<div id="product-2">    
<div class="size-field">
    <div id="size-label">s</div>
<div class="number-input">
    <input id="Small" class="product-quantity" type="number" name="Small" 
min="0" max="9999" data-product-id="2"></input>
</div>
 </div>
        <div id="size-label">m</div>
 <div class="number-input">
    <input id="Medium" class="product-quantity" type="number" name="Medium" 
 min="0" max="9999" data-product-id="2"></input>
</div>
<br clear="all">

<div class="name-number-header"><h5>HEADER<h5></div>
 <div class="name-number-field-container" data-size="Small">small:
 </div>
    <div class="name-number-field-container" data-size="Medium">medium:
 </div>
    </div>
```

js :

```
$('.product-quantity').each(function () {
    $(this).data('val', this.value);
}).on('change', function () {
    var val = $(this).val(),
        old = $(this).data('val'),
        input = $('<div/>', {'class': 'name-number-field'}).html('<input 
             class="name-field" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">'),
        ele = $(this).closest('[id^="product"]').find('[data-size="' + this.name + '"]'),
        inc = val >= old;

    if (inc) {
        $(input).insertAfter(ele.nextUntil(':not(.name-number-field)').last()
        .length ? ele.nextUntil(':not(.name-number-field)').last() : ele);
    } else {
        ele.nextUntil(':not(.name-number-field)').last().remove();
    }

    $(this).data('val', this.value);
});
```

Comment: You will need a `for loop` in here don't see any other way.

Comment: Seems like that's not the only issue. If you hit a down arrow first then it still generates content.

Comment: that does seem to be true. it is interesting that in my actually project when I use this script it does not do that.

Comment: You selectors are too complicated.  Why do you need to create another `<div>` element ***after it*** for each input??  Why not put the div element in using `appendTo`? Instead of `insertAfter`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/56/)**

You need to put a for loop outside the code that created the elements:

```
  }).on('change', function () {
         var val = $(this).val(),
        old = $(this).data('val');
  for (var count=0; count<Math.abs(val-old) ; count++)
  {
       ...
  }
```

**Update based on comments**

See **[this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/65/)**. There were some problems that were in the original code:

1. The data was not initialised. Fix: `if( !startVal || startVal.length == 0 )`
2. The comparison was not with ints. Fix: `inc = (parseInt(val) >= parseInt(old));`

Comment: OH My Goodnesss! that works amazingly. Thank you!!! I will have to do a little investigating to see how this is actually work. but thank you. What is the Math.abs?

Comment: @anmaree - glad to help. Please accept the answer if it worked for you. Math.abs() will return the absolute value of a number. This means that Math.abs(3) -> 3 and that Math.abs(-3) -> 3 (i.e the positive value).

Comment: if you are still available for help... the code is exactly what I am looking for, however for some reason if I have say 4 in the number field and then I type 10 in the number field it gets screwy. all the field disappear. If I do 10 first and then 4, it just adds 4 to the 10.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is checking for the direction of change between old and new only, not how much difference there is. If it's an increase (of any amount), you add an element; if it's a decrease, you remove one.

You need to wrap that code in a loop and execute it as many times as the difference between old and new.

```
for (var i=0 ; i<Math.abs(val-old) ; i++) {
  if (inc) {
    $(input).insertAfter(ele.nextUntil(':not(.name-number-field)').last()
    .length ? ele.nextUntil(':not(.name-number-field)').last() : ele);
  } else {
    ele.nextUntil(':not(.name-number-field)').last().remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: I can understand that. I am just not sure how it should look in my script i already have

Comment: i am having trouble with this: here is what I got : http://jsfiddle.net/7PhJZ/54/

Comment: +1 Since the Math.abs go me started on my answer. The for loop just needed to be higher. Also var i==0 should be var i=0.

Comment: @acarlon - you are right. I corrected the i==0 problem, but left the rest in favor of your answer, which I upvoted. Thanks.